# ¿Por qué no me sale la imagen ni la excepción con este codigo?

Tags: java

```
package gráficos;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ImagenesJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MarcoImagen marco=new MarcoImagen();
        marco.setVisible(true);
        marco.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

}

class MarcoImagen extends JFrame
    {
       public MarcoImagen()
       {

           setTitle("Marco con imagenes");
           setBounds(750, 300, 300, 200);
           LaminaImagen lamina=new LaminaImagen();
           add(lamina);

       }


    }

class LaminaImagen extends JPanel
    {
    private Image imagen;

    public void PaintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        File archivo=new File("C/Users/admin/Desktop/Analisis de sitemas/Aprendizaje/Ejercicios_AprenderAProgramar/src/gráficos/Auto.png");
        try{
        imagen=ImageIO.read(archivo);
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("La imagen no se ha podido encontrar");
        }

        g.drawImage(imagen, 5, 5, null);
    }
    }
```

Comment: En ningún momento estas llamando al método   `PaintComponent`

Comment: Gracias debía colocarlo en minúscula

Comment: Y... ¿por qué no usas `BufferedImage`, [como indica la doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html): `BufferedImage img = null; String imgPath = newString("C/Users/admin/Desktop/Analisis de sitemas/Aprendizaje/Ejercicios_AprenderAProgramar/src/gráficos/Auto.png");
try {
    img = ImageIO.read(new File(imgPath));
} catch (IOException e) {
}
` [Aquí un ejemplo completo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/examples/LoadImageApp.java) por si te quedan dudas.